# Como solucionar error openssl al incluir mi libreria

Tags: c++

El error que me da es el siguiente:

> ||=== Build: Debug in cheke (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>   main.cpp|15|fatal error: openssl/md5.h: No such
>   file or directory| ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0
>   minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Sin embargo lo inclui de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <openssl/md5.h>
#include <openssl/des.h>
```

Aún así sigue dandome error y sin reconocerlo. Estoy utilizando el compilador mingw y se supone que son para mi mingw ya que lo descargue para mingw. Alguien sabe como podría solucionarlo o cual es el problema. Cualquier cosa puedo aportar para detallar más.

Estoy haciendo desde consola y con ide, el ide que uso es codeblocks pero no tiene mucho que ver. Sigo dandome el mismo problema.

Captura:
error actual:

> In file included from main.cpp:15:0: openssl/md5.h:62:27: fatal error:
>   openssl/e_os2.h: No such file or directory  #include 
>                              ^ compilation terminated.

Codigo y error del fichero:

> gcc unwand.cpp -I"include" -lcrypto -o unwand unwand.cpp: In function
>   'int main(int, char**)': unwand.cpp:42:60: error: 'malloc' was not
>   declared in this scope   unsigned char *wandData = (unsigned char
>   *)malloc(fileSize);
>                                                               ^ unwand.cpp:182:15: error: 'free' was not declared in this scope
>   free(wandData);

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48696/discussion-on-question-by-omar-alami-como-solucionar-error-openssl-al-incluir-mi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba con:

```
g++ main.cpp -L"directorio" -lcrypto -I"directorio/include" -o ejecutable
```

donde "directorio" es la carpeta donde esta los archivos .a

añade:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: lo intente gracias por ayudarme pero creo que es algo del openssl que me descargue.. porque no doy ni una ;(

Comment: tambien hice con el compilador de windows y me muestra otros errores.

Comment: bueno he hecho esto y bueno funciona pero supongo el codigo no es correcto pondre el ultimo error que me da por si alguien le quiere un ojo aunque ya sea un poco salu2

Comment: añade malloc y free

Comment: es la misma solución que te pase